# Computer description becomes empty

Tags: networking

In one of my system connected to my network, I am facing a wired problem. When the computer starts it is shown in the network for sometime and then goes missing. When I checked the computer, Its `Computer description` gets blank automatically. After restarting the system it works again for few minutes.

I have installed fresh licensed copy of Win XP into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above problem is common in WinXP service pack 3. The solution for this is to run `Windows Update` and update your system. This will solve your problem.